# Python: Replace a cell value in Dataframe with if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix with that looks like this:

```
    com 0 1 2 3 4 5
AAA  0  5 0 4 2 1 4
ABC  0  9 8 9 1 0 3
ADE  1  4 3 5 1 0 1
BCD  1  6 7 8 3 4 1
BCF  2  3 4 2 1 3 0 ...
```

Where `AAA, ABC` ... is the dataframe index. The dataframe columns are `com 0 1 3 4 5 6`

I want to set the cell values in my dataframe equal to 0 when the row values of `com` is equal the column "number". So for instance, the above matrix will look like:

```
    com 0 1 2 3 4 5
AAA  0  0 0 4 2 1 4
ABC  0  0 8 9 1 0 3
ADE  1  4 0 5 1 0 1
BCD  1  6 0 8 3 4 1
BCF  2  3 4 0 1 3 0 ...
```

I tried to iterate over rows and use both `.loc` and `.ix` but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just require some `numpy` trick

```
In [22]:

print df
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  5  0  4  2  1  4
0  9  8  9  1  0  3
1  4  3  5  1  0  1
1  6  7  8  3  4  1
2  3  4  2  1  3  0

[5 rows x 6 columns]
In [23]:
#making a masking matrix, 0 where column and index values equal, 1 elsewhere, kind of the vectorized way of doing if TURE 0, else 1
print df*np.where(df.columns.values==df.index.values[..., np.newaxis], 0,1)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  4  2  1  4
0  0  8  9  1  0  3
1  4  0  5  1  0  1
1  6  0  8  3  4  1
2  3  4  0  1  3  0

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Great! that works fine. I had to make a small change though:
`print df*np.where(df.columns.values==df.com.values[..., np.newaxis], 0,1)` where I change `df.index.values` for `df.com.values`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
for line in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[matrix[line][0]+1]=0
```

**NOTE**
Depending on your matrix setup you may not need the +1

Basically it takes the first digit of each line in the matrix and uses that as the index of the value to change to 0

i.e. if the row was

```
    c 0 1 2 3 4 5
AAA 4 3 2 3 9 5 9,
```

it would change the 5 below the number 4 to 0

```
    c 0 1 2 3 4 5
AAA 4 3 2 3 9 0 9
```